# Bootstrap (JS/HTML CDN importing of JQuery) returns Uncaught Error

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to import jQuery so I can use bootstraps dropdown menus, but I am having a bit of trouble, as I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires at least jQuery v1.9.1 but less than v4.0.0
```

While the error seems logical, I don't understand why it says I don't have jQuery installed, as I am definetly importing it:

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

I am importing jquery before bootstrap, so I don't understand what what is creating the error.
This is a part of an electron app if that helps or has anything to do with the issue

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Please read [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: Please look at the order of the script/stylesheets that you are loading into your html. The stylesheets must be referenced before the scripts

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows the starter template for Bootstrap 4 which can be found [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template). Following this example should get you fixed up. Notice that the script tags are located just above the closing `</body>` tag. The order in which the scripts are listed is also important.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```